# File Input in ML-Lex

Tags: sml, lex, smlnj, ml-lex

How to take input from a file after running `ml-lex filename.lex` and then using `makeLexer` function?

I am trying to do : `val lexer = makeLexer(fn n => valOf(inputLine(openIn("test.txt"))));`

[I have already done `open TextIO;` so that I am able to use `openIn`.]

But, this gives me an error after I run `lexer();` :

> uncaught exception Io [Io: openIn failed on "test.txt", Too many open files]
>
> > raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/text-io-fn.sml:783.25-783.71

Comment: Could you post your .lex file or preferrably a minimal subset that causes this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing the problem in your posted code, I'm guessing that you are opening multiple files in a loop, and failing to close them,

```
fun foo _ 0 = ()
  | foo filenm n = let val _ = TextIO.openIn(filenm) in foo filenm (n - 1) end

fun bar _ 0 = ()
  | bar filenm n =
   let val ins = TextIO.openIn(filenm)
       val _ = TextIO.inputLine(ins)
       val _ = TextIO.closeIn(ins)
    in bar filenm (n - 1) end
```

In the following transcript, the call to **bar** works with 1024, as it opens then closes each input stream sequentially, however the subsequent call to **foo** fails with the error, as it hits the platform defined limit on the number of open file descriptors.

```
val foo = fn : string -> int -> unit
val bar = fn : string -> int -> unit
- bar "toomanyfiles.sml" 1024;
val it = () : unit
- foo "toomanyfiles.sml" 1024;

uncaught exception Io [Io: openIn failed on "toomanyfiles.sml", Too many open files]
  raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/text-io-fn.sml:783.25-783.71
```